# type "HTMLDivElement" is not assignable to type "Node" in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom

Just to be clear, all I know about Angular are components and a tiny bit of directives. If my question requires more advanced topics such as services or what not then just let me know that.

Here is my folder structure

[image: Folder Structure of my Project]

Here is my App Component HTML

```html
 <app-game-control 
    [even] = "evenComponent"
    [odd] = "oddComponent">
</app-game-control>
<div class="outer"
    #outer>
      <div class="inner-even"
      #evenComponent>
        <app-even
          *ngFor="let value of even">
            {{value}} is Even
        </app-even>
      </div>

      <div class="inner-odd"
      #oddComponent>
        <app-odd
          *ngFor="let value of odd">
        {{value}} is Odd
        </app-odd>
      </div>
</div>
```

Game-Control TS file

```js
@Input() even?: HTMLDivElement
@Input() odd?: HTMLDivElement
@Input() outer?: HTMLDivElement

resetDisplay() {
    this.even?.remove()
    this.odd?.remove()
    // the next 2 lines are the problem
    this.outer?.appendChild(this.even) // it expects a Node, while I declared it as an HTMLDivElement
    this.outer?.appendChild(this.odd) // it expects a Node, while I declared it as an HTMLDivElement
    clearInterval(this.intervalFunction)
   }
```

Now, I know Angular encapsulates the DOM tree. When I access `outer` in Game Control and try to manipulate the DOM in App Component, I suppose that does not work. In this case, I want to add even and odd in the template of the App component. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an HTMLDivElement is a Node, to fix your error you could cast your elements to Node as:

```js
this.outer?.appendChild(this.even as Node)
this.outer?.appendChild(this.odd as Node)
```

Said so, I think that's not the best approach to achieve what you want in Angular, manipulating the DOM of a parent component from a child is not recommended.

A more correct approach in this case is to make your game controller notify the parent component that you're game component needs to be reset.

You can do so using an @Output on your child component:

```js
/*game-control.component.ts*/

@Output controlsNeedReset = new EventEmitter<void>();

resetDisplay() {
    this.controlsNeedReset.emit();
}
```

And then intercepting it in your parent component:

```html
<!--app.component.html-->

<app-game-control (controlsNeedReset)="reset()">
</app-game-control>
```

```js
/*app.component.ts*/

reset() {
  // Here you can reset data for your game, so for example:
  this.even = [];
  this.odd = [];
}
```

You can check [Sharing data between child and parent directives and components](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) for reference